# SQL get entries where on attribute is max

Tags: sql, max

I have the following dataset:

| id | id_rev | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 08.01.2022 |
| 1 | 0 | 31.02.2021 |
| 2 | 2 | 28.01.2017 |
| 2 | 1 | 25.07.2021 |
| 2 | 0 | 25.07.2021 |

I am looking for a SQL query that can return an entry per id but only the one where the id_rev is maximum. So in this case it should return these two rows:

(id=1, id_rev=1,time)
(id=2, id_rev=2, time)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One canonical approach uses `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id_rev DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable t
)

SELECT id, id_rev, time
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY id;
```

Another approach would be to use exists logic:

```sql
SELECT id, id_rev, time
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM yourTable t2
    WHERE t2.id = t1.id AND t2.id_rev > t1.id_rev
);
```

Answer (score 0):

@result =
SELECT
*,
RANK()
OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id_rev DESC) AS Rank
FROM dataset ORDER BY Rank;

@result =
SELECT *
FROM @result
WHERE Rank = 1;